# Print Several Outlook MailItems

Tags: c#, printing, outlook

I have a pst that has a bunch of emails I want to print using the Microsoft Document Image Writer so that I have a folder, //lawyers/ediscovery/emails/ that has 00001.tiff 00002.tiff etc. In Word or Excel, I can pass the Workbook or Document a filepath to the PrintOut method, but the Outlook MailItem interop's PrintOut doesn't take any arguments, instead only uses the default printer's attributies. I don't have time to type the Bates number for every email (thousands to tens of thousands). Any help on how to tell Outlook where to print to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not possible inside of outlook as you say the printout command is not that useful.
I think the only way would be to use a 3rd party pst > tiff tool.

Comment: Pretty much. Actual final solution:

Open a new word document, paste the appropriate portions from the MailItem, and format them, then print that document.

Comment: ouch .. There is a way to get a number printed as a user property under the TO and FROMs, but I guess you need the number as filename as you are printing to tiff. Another wy to go would be to convert to EML and then print from another client that has better printing support.